# How to have a property in sync with an other in a Typescript object in a generic way?

Tags: typescript

I would like to express than a property of an object is "in sync" with another property in the same object.

Imagine we have a type Widget, which represents a UI component that stores a certain type.

```
type Widget = {
  id: string
  type: string
}

const datepicker: Widget = {
  id: "datepicker",
  type: "string" // stores an ISO string
}

const numberpicker: Widget = {
  id: "numberpicker",
  type: "number"
}
```

Suppose now that we have a Config object, which defines that some inputs have a certain type and are served by a certain widget. What I want is to guarantee that only a compatible widget is used.

```
type ConfigItem = {
  name: string
  type: string
  widget: Widget
}

type Config = Array<ConfigItem>

const config: Config = [{
  name: "birthdate",
  type: "string",
  widget: datepicker, // OK because a datepicker manages a string
}, {
  name: "age",
  type: "number", 
  widget: numberpicker // OK because a numberpicker manages a number
}, {
  name: "numberPets",
  type: "number", 
  widget: datepicker // KO because a datepicker can't manage a number
}]
```

I don't know how to express that or even if it is possible...
And I want to write it as a generic way, not just for this example.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you have very little type constraints in your code. Let's say that you're able to express the compile-time type restriction that you're asking for. What happens at runtime if someone does `datepicker.type = 'number'`? Because of a lack type information, the compiler will not produce  a warning, and all of the sudden the type constraint on your config items is no longer upheld.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
type Widget = { id: string } & ({ type:"string" } | { type:"number" })

const datepicker: Widget = {
  id: "datepicker",
  type: "string" // stores an ISO string
}

const numberpicker: Widget = {
  id: "numberpicker",
  type: "number"
}

type ConfigItem = { name:string } & ({ type:"string", widget: { type:"string" } } | { type:"number", widget: {type:"number"} })

type Config = Array<ConfigItem>

const config: Config = [{
  name: "birthdate",
  type: "string",
  widget: datepicker, // OK because a datepicker manages a string
}, {
  name: "age",
  type: "number", 
  widget: numberpicker // OK because a numberpicker manages a number
}, {
  name: "numberPets",
  type: "number", 
  widget: datepicker // KO because a datepicker can't manage a number
}]
```

[image]
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glgEwOYWFAvFA3lRAuKAZ2ACc4A7JKAXygDIoAKHUSPAImLMvZqgB9sUVhA7kArgFsARhBK9qASgCwAKDUBjAPbliUBAENgEMHA0BrOQXjJUGbGqi4EBdoeOmLc9gBpHw8FEoTlIKJF4AegiiYC0SCEIoA3IoAEkAZQB5GO4kNWo1TR09CRk5T0sSa0QUNEwsf3xg0tkSCu8-VScRVxbvfMLVESgAYR0AMzgkVONJexxyA0lRLjC%20BmYAthDc3ygAdxrUAhZAjlWePlpBU%202%20%20R8Do%20ATnvZ79lolQeGx8kmqJgAIIkEgGEAAHj%20AJmEEkAD5BtpdGhkQCCNCpvYANoNLpQRbLVzSOAkYAAC3cEF8-h6wQu4U6TkOthe%20iMJjMlUeUSgmQA0lBZBoDOJCNADOyPFy5FBJMkDChEpKGflHninISguxFdSmVttR9Hv4WbUCPd2iQoLyBUKICKxRKCVJWpa5QqlUlnWUSGqHPitb0XXIAAqoQg0-F097Bh5QE3PAhUt28-nZYWi8Ve5Myq0i8gAcjQ8sWKC993yAF0gA)

Comment: Thanks! Good idea. However, I implicitly expected to resolve it in a generic way. I have updated my question.

Comment: need more context